# Embed a plot into GUI

Tags: python, pyqt4

I found a website scikit-rf

http://scikit-rf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/plotting.html

It can create smith plot by following code

```
ntwk = rf.Network("my data path")
ntwk.plot_s_smith()
```

Then I want to embed it to my python gui.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import skrf as rf
import numpy as np
class PrettyWidget(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PrettyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1200,700)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('NRW')



        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        grid.addWidget(self.canvas, 3,0,2,12)

    def plot1(self):

        self.figure.clf()
        self.figure.tight_layout()
        self.canvas.draw()



if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    GUI = PrettyWidget()
    GUI.show()
    app.exec_()
```

But I have no idea how to put or modify code below

```
ntwk = rf.Network("my data path")
ntwk.plot_s_smith()
```

Would anyone tell me if you have any iedas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Network.plot_s_smith](http://scikit-rf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/skrf.network.Network.plot_s_smith.html) has an `ax` keyword to plot on existing *Axes* object. So you can modify your plot function like this:

```
def plot1(self):

    self.figure.clf()
    ntwk = rf.Network("my data path")
    ntwk.plot_s_smith(ax=self.figure.gca()) 
    self.figure.tight_layout()
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks! I can show my result now! By the way self.figure.tight_layout() is removed or it will show error.

Comment: Probably because there are no axes yet at this point. You can move it after `plot_s_smith`.